# array with different elements c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to put in an array some data from show.

I have this function:

```
addShow(string name, string theatre, string day, string hour, int totalTickets, float price)
```

I have a dinamic array which maximum length is the maximum shows that can be done.

```
arrayShows = new int[totalShows];
```

Now, I need to put in this array the data of each show, how can I do it?

I thought something like this:

```
count = 0;
arrayShows[count]= name;
arrayShows[count+1]= theatre;
arrayShows[count+2]= day;
arrayShows[count+3]= hour;
arrayShows[count+4]= totalTickets;
arrayShows[count+5]= price;

count += 6;
```

But as you can see if the maximum shows is 5, this is not correct because I can only put some data from the first show, but the other 4 shows won't be stored.

Could I do a bidimensional dinamic array to do solve this problem?

Comment: You probably want an array of structures or several arrays.

Comment: Change `string name` to `const string& name` to avoid copying the strings

Comment: Don't use a floating-point number for the price. Store the cents as an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to create either `structure` or `class` which represents a show. It is not that difficult:

```
struct Show {
    Show() = default;

    Show(const std::string& name, const std::string& theater,
        const std::string& day, const std::string& hour,
        int totalTickets, float price)
        : name(name)
        , theater(theater)
        , day(day)
        , hour(hour)
        , totalTickets(totalTickets)
        , price(price)
    {}

    std::string name;
    std::string theater;
    std::string day;
    std::string hour;
    int totalTickets;
    float price;
};
```

Then, avoid using dynamic arrays and use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<Show> shows(totalShows);
shows[0] = Show(name, theater, day, hour, totalTickets, price);
```

Or just add new elements on the fly:

```
shows.emplace_back(name, theater, day, hour, totalTickets, price);
```

There are, of course, other approaches like using [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), but you do not need to make things more complicated then they are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store different types in array you can use C++17 `std::any` or `std::variant`.
`std::any`:

```
std::vector<std::any> arrayShows;
arrayShows.push_back(name);
arrayShows.push_back(theatre);
arrayShows.push_back(day);
arrayShows.push_back(hour);
arrayShows.push_back(totalTickets);
arrayShows.push_back(price);
```

`std::variant`:

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, float, std::string>> arrayShows;
arrayShows.push_back(name);
arrayShows.push_back(theatre);
arrayShows.push_back(day);
arrayShows.push_back(hour);
arrayShows.push_back(totalTickets);
arrayShows.push_back(price);
```

Or if you cannot use C++17 you could implement your own solution using [type erasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QGcVXgEVMJg).

Answer (score 0):

Create class for your data and then make array of the objects of class that will do